# ReactJS methods and useState stuff break into a separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called **Invoice.js**. This has more than 1000 lines of code.
I do want to break a few methods and their relevant useState stuff to a separate file.

I have an array called `items` and API call to fill the array.

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

 // load items
  const loadItems = async () => {
    try {
      let items = await axios.get("/item");
      setItems(items.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert({
        showAlert: true,
        severity: "error",
        message: "Customer loading failed!",
      });
    }
  };
```

Please note that I am calling this array in the `useEffect` hook.

```
// use effect hook
  useEffect(() => {
    //load active agents
    loadAgent();

    //load items
    loadItems();
  }, []);
```

I do want to break this whole thing into a separate file and just import the `items` array.

Another case is `addItem` method.

```
  const addItem = (e) => {
    // check this item already added
    const foundItem = initialValues.items.find((itm) => itm.id === item.id);

    if (foundItem) {
      setAlert({
        showAlert: true,
        severity: "error",
        message: "This item already added!",
      });
    } else {
      const originalItem = items.find((el) => el.id === item.id);
      const { id, description, size } = originalItem;
      const newEl = {
        id,
        description,
        size,
        unitPrice: Number(item.unitPrice).toFixed(2),
        qty: item.qty,
        amount: (Number(item.qty) * Number(item.unitPrice)).toFixed(2),
      };
      setInitialValues({
        ...initialValues,
        items: [...initialValues.items, newEl],
      });
    }
  };
```

In this case, this function depends on both items array and `initialValues` object.

How do I achieve this using React, with keeping mind if something went wrong inside these functions I need to fire the `setAlert` method in the Invocie.js component.

Comment: Remember that hooks can only be used within components. 
You could probably split the Invoice component into smaller components where every component will be responsible for something else, i.e. list of items, total values, customer info etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you need is custom hook.Something like this

```
const useItems = setAlert => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // load items
  const loadItems = async () => {
    try {
      const items = await axios.get("/item");
      setItems(items.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert({
        showAlert : true,
        severity  : "error",
        message   : "Customer loading failed!",
      });
    }
  };

  return [items, loadItems];
};
```

And you call it on anywhere like this. As it was before

```
const [itemd, loadItems] = useItems(setAlert);

useEffect(() => {
  loadItems()
}, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a custom hook, pass in all dependencies as parameters and return all the functions and states:

```
  function useItems({ setAlert }) {
     const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

     async function loadItems() { ... }
     function addItem(item) { ... }

     useEffect(() => { loadItems(); }, []);

     return { items, addItem };
  }

  // Then embed as
 function setAlert() { ... }
 const { items, addItem } = useItems({ setAlert });
```

The hook is then independent from the component, and can be moved into another file.

Answer (score 1):

I would say custom Hooks are the solutions you are looking for, to be exact on your use case -

You might want to create a custom hook useItems and transfer the code of useState and useEffect to that file and just write

> const {data, error} = useItems();

Your useItems could be like

```
export default () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(null)
   useEffect(() => {
//your fetch code
}, []) 

return {data: items, error}
}
```

To make this generic what I did it, I create custom hooks for different types of network calls.

like usePost, useGet etc handling the different data trigger cases I had.